# Identifying bare soil in agricultural areas using NDVI and Bare soil index in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

print(maskedCollection)

Veuillez être plus précis sur les zones auxquelles vous faites référence (vous pouvez joindre une capture d'écran par exemple) et faites en sorte que votre code soit exécutable par n'importe qui, car actuellement les tables que vous utilisez ont un accès limité

Comment: Please be more specific about which areas you are referring to (you can attach a screenshot for example) and make it so that your code is runnable by anyone, since currently the tables you are using have limited access

Answer (score 1):

While I'm still not sure exactly what part of the code is not doing what you expect, I did notice your code is quite messy, and that easily leads to mistakes. A few examples:

- You define your sentinel image collection about three different times (as `dataset`, `S2`, and `S2collection`), and every time it's slightly different: some you apply cloud masking to, and some you don't. This isn't good. You want to keep your S2 consistent throughout your calculations.
- You also define your functions `addNDVI` and `baresoilindex` twice. This, again, is likely to lead to mistakes.
- Your variable names do not reflect the contents of your variables.

Here is a much cleaner and simpler version of your code, which should be much easier to analyze and search for bugs:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d4ae5f5e5788354cfbf1e96f501065b3

Comment: I'm not sure that is a question for this forum, as it does not relate to GIS directly. I suggest you take a look around the scientific literature on the topic which may outline the reasons why albedo can increase in general.

Comment: If you want to add the image to your map, you can add Map.addLayer(alb,{min:0,max:4000,palette:['black','gray','white']},'Albedo') for example. As far as the scientific problem goes, I'm not sure I can help you as it is not my area of expertise, sorry

Comment: @RoseDjamko your chart is empty because your alb image does not intersect with your site, if you add it to the map it's barely visible, you've masked it too much

Comment: @RoseDjamko moving forward you need to either create a new question (if it is relevant to GIS), or go over your code with a supervisor or colleague, since this platform is not meant for this kind of interaction, so I will no longer be helping you. Good luck!